# SQlite: select into?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm not sure if I can use select into to import data from another table like this:

```
select * into
  bookmark1 
from bookmark;
```

Is it true that SQlite doesn't support this syntax? are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
insert into bookmark1 select * from bookmark
```

Comment: This assumes bookmark1 already exists, while select into creates a new table.

Comment: @vit, yes of course. It's for the case we want to import again in a table.

Comment: @Nick: I'm sure you know this, I just thought this should be made clear for anyone why may stumble upon this question later. :)

Answer (score 192):

You could do:

```
create table bookmark1 as select * from bookmark;
```

Comment: sorry i can't give any point coz I'm new, but your suggestion works well.
Thanks =)

Comment: Perfect answer and concise & to the point. +1 and lots of kudos.

Comment: any way to get this work in two situations, where the table exists already (overwrite) and where it does not (create new table)?

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the one accepted as the answer!

Comment: @Glaucon now you can upvote this answer, and select it as the accepted answer. It will help everyone who comes here

Comment: its same syntax as oracle , just saying.

Comment: If you want this to work even when the table already exists, then run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table> beforehand.

Comment: Is it possible to make this also copy attributes like `primary key` or `not null`?

Answer (score 23):

I assume that bookmark1 is a new table that you have created which is same as the bookmark table. In that case you can use the following format.

```
CREATE TABLE bookmark1 AS SELECT * FROM bookmark;
```

Or you can also use the insert statement with subquery. For different insert statement options refer: [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Answer (score 11):

```
create table NewTable as
select * from OldTable where 1 <> 1
```

This will copy data structure for you.

Comment: This is quite clever.

Comment: wrap this SQL in a try-block (or equivalent construct) in  the programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

BUT be careful: "create table" from the other in such a way is not saving Data Types of new table's fields as so as they were in the source table, therefore I would prefer to "create table" with a separate statement & "insert into" statement also to do separately - as was mentioned above:

```
insert into bookmark_backup select * from bookmark;"
```