# SELECT INTO statement in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Does sqlite support the `SELECT INTO` statement?

Actually I am trying to save the data in `table1` into `table2` as a backup of my database before modifying the data.

When I try using the `SELECT INTO` statement:

```
SELECT * INTO equipments_backup FROM equipments;
```

I get a syntax error:

> "Last Error Message:near "INTO":syntax
> error".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQlite: select into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027488/sqlite-select-into)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

sqlite does not support SELECT INTO.

You can probably use this form instead:

`INSERT INTO equipments_backup  SELECT * FROM equipments;`

Comment: This does not work in SQLite 3.8.11.1 (OSX version) nor in Firefox's SQLite Manager plug-in. `CREATE TABLE ... AS ...` does work.

Answer (score 178):

Instead of

```
SELECT * INTO equipments_backup FROM equipments
```

try

```
CREATE TABLE equipments_backup AS SELECT * FROM equipments
```

Comment: Nice... `CREATE TABLE equipments_backup AS SELECT * FROM equipments`

Comment: This should be the solution answer

Answer (score 6):

SQlite didn't have INSERT INTO syntax.

In 2019, I use **TEMPORARY** keyword to create temporary table and INSERT data to temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE equipments_backup(field1 TEXT, field2 REAL)
INSERT INTO equipments_backup SELECT field1, field2 FROM equipments
```