# Python: T-SQL EQuivalent for Sqlite3?

Tags: python, t-sql, sqlite

I have the following MS-SQL based query which I need to convert into Sqlite3 based database

```
DECLARE @status int, @nextPriority int
SELECT @status = status FROM status WHERE nameStatus = '234'
```

I then have to use that variable in an INSERT query.

One way I think is to execute query and bind variables but I am willing to execute all queries in a Go. Is it possible?

I am using Python 2.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sqlite does not support stored procedures, as such.

You can either `SELECT` directly into the `INSERT` statement ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2361961/839436)), or just break it up into two separate prepared statements.

sqlite doesn't have quite the same amount of overhead for queries and their responses, so it generally isn't that big of a deal.