# How to turn Access statement into SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

This works in Access but I am trying to get it to work in SQLite. No success so far. This is trying to create a new table from selecting certain columns from another table using left join.

SELECT Sample1.empID, Sample1.Name, Sample2.LOB INTO New 
FROM Sample1 LEFT JOIN Sample2 ON Sample1.empID = Sample2.[empID,LOB];

Can anyone modify that to fit into an SQL statement?

Comment: Please see the answers to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2361921/42346

Comment: How do I add the left join though? That's what I am having trouble with.