# Why an query in VB6 with SQL Server and SQLite does not work?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, vb6, syntax-error

I have an app in VB6. The app works with dbs SQL Server and SQLite. I installed ODBC drivers for SQLite. I made connections to dbs cn and cnsqlite. The app has to filter data from SQL Server, create a new empty db SQLite and insert data into db SQLite. I create a query and a command

```
sqlStr2 = "Select * INTO " & rsad.Fields("Table_Name") & " FROM (select * from  [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=server2\SQLEXPRESS;Database=base1;uid=user;pwd=userpwd;].dbo." & rsad.Fields("Table_Name") & filter & ")"
cnsqlite.Execute sqlStr2, dbFailOnError
```

The app in the command arises the error
only one SQL statement allowed

I deleted in the query (select * from). The same error arised. Before with db MS Access these statements normally worked.
What to do? How rightly need to compose the query?

Temur Yakubov

I deleted in the query (select * from).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT INTO statement in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361921/select-into-statement-in-sqlite)

Comment: because sqlite doesn't support the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `select * into` you need to use `create table tablename as`

```
sqlStr2 = "create table " & rsad.Fields("Table_Name") & " as select * FROM (select * from  [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=server2\SQLEXPRESS;Database=base1;uid=user;pwd=userpwd;].dbo." & rsad.Fields("Table_Name") & filter & ")"
cnsqlite.Execute sqlStr2, dbFailOnError
```

If above query is not working then you might try to create a temp table first then insert it into your desired table.

```
Dim sqlSubquery as String
sqlSubquery = "SELECT * FROM [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=server2\SQLEXPRESS;Database=base1;uid=user;pwd=userpwd;].dbo." & rsad.Fields("Table_Name") & filter
cnsqlite.Execute "CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS " & sqlSubquery, dbFailOnError

'Select data from temporary table
Dim sqlMainQuery as String
sqlMainQuery = "create table " & rsad.Fields("Table_Name") &"
```

as select * from temp_table"
cnsqlite.Execute sqlMainQuery, dbFailOnError

Comment: ^ 2 viable alternatives.  SQL Lite doesn't support all standard SQL, but the problem can still be solved :)

Comment: Dear Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur I tried your suggestions. Both give an error: near ".": syntax error (1)