# What SQL query do I need in order to add lots of empty rows to a table at once?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I understand that what I am asking for may not make a lot of sense, but I none the less have a particular need for it. I have a table that has 500 rows in it. I have another table that has 500 more rows, that I need to merge into the first table. The easiest way I know how to do that is to add 500 rows to the first table, and then use an update statement because then I have a primary key to use to pair the first and second tables.

So how can I add 500 blank rows to my first table? I've been trying to think of a query that would do that, but haven't been able to come up with anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert to one table from another table:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name)
SELECT account_no, name
FROM customers
WHERE city = 'Newark';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert into statement:
[SQlite: select into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027488/sqlite-select-into)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the tables contain the same data structure, you can use a simple query to insert them into your table:

```
INSERT INTO tableOne SELECT * FROM tableTwo
```

If you have to manually map the fields, you'll have to change it to the field level insert, such as:

```
INSERT INTO tableOne(columnOne,columnTwo) SELECT column3, column4 FROM tableTwo
```

You can add the standard WHERE statements to these as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like Steve Wellens beat me to the punch while I was answering. That's what I get for getting distracted mid-post. :)

Comment: Looking at you statement, you have == in the field5 validation. That should be field5 = 2, if I'm not mistaken.