# How to dump a row from a SQLite database and import it into another database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I currently want to dump a row from a SQLite database, transfer it over a network, and import it into the SQLite database on another phone. How would I properly dump the row and import it later? I looked around and I see a number of people mentioning .sql files, but is there an Android-specific way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for SELECT INTO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Which does not exist on Android/SQLite.

Comment: @CL. Sounds like you're qualified to answer the question. ;).  In that case, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027488/sqlite-select-into

Comment: As I understood the question as non related with "SELECT INTO" operation as the other comments suggest, but It's related with communication between 2 mobile phones (one has a row data, and the another one has to receive it). Correct me if I misunderstood, please?

Comment: That's correct, Freerider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have exact same table structure on both source and target sides (otherwise question would not make much sense), and you probably already know your table structure.

In that case, if you simply `SELECT` row you want to export (for example using Java code):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 12345;
```

you would know row contents, so you can construct `INSERT` statement for target table, which should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( col1,   col2,  ...)
             VALUES ('val1', 'val2', ...);
```

All you need now is to execute this insert statement on target side (using Java or sqlite3 command line).