# how to fetch data from 2 sqlite tables and insert it into 3rd table in android? i am new to android...i have tried bt it does not work?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

table 1 is MsgTable, 2nd is ContactTable & the third 1 is KeyTable...
i have to select data from first 2 tables & insert it into 3rd table??

public void setKeyValues(String msg_id, String contact_id )//insert intokeytable(msgid - contact)
    {

```
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Msg_Id", msg_id);
        values.put("Contact_Id", contact_id);
        i = db.insert("KeyTable", null, values);//contact

        if(i != 0)
        {
        }
    }   

public ArrayList<String> getValues()
{
       ArrayList<String> arr = null;
    try
    {
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c1= null; 
        Cursor c2 = null; 
        c1 = db.rawQuery("select Msg_id from KeyTable where Contact_id = 1", null);
        while(c1.moveToNext())
        {
            String  msg = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("MSG"));
            String str = msg ;
            arr.add(str);
            Log.d("fuuast",str);    
        }

        c2 = db.rawQuery("select Contact_id from KeyTable where Msg_id = 1", null);
        while(c2.moveToNext())
        {
            String  contact = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Contact"));
            String str = contact ;

            arr.add(str);

            Log.d("fuuast",str);

        }

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return arr;
}
```

}

Comment: that three tables are in same database or not?

Comment: yeah, tables are in same database....

Comment: Use sqlite INSERT...SELECT as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027488/sqlite-select-into - you just need to do a join for the two tables.

Comment: i will help you clarify one thing friend , that getvalues() arraylist values are all where you used for insert in the table?

Comment: yeah i used getvalues()arraylist for selecting & inserting in 3rd table....

Comment: Fetch 2 tables have any Foreign key link? how about your insert table structure?

Comment: yeah friend u you used the arraylist for getting the values form the two tables i'm asking where you used those values for insert into third table

Comment: i never seen those getValues() of arraylist values in your code so put your insert method code friend

Comment: @B M What you say without a foreign key link cant able to fetch the data ah?

Comment: if you explain more about your table structure we will give you some codes

Comment: @Sara_Ali i have a code to fetch data answer my previous stuff

Comment: @Sara_Ali first of all you have to fetch the data from your first two table then stored in some datastructure like string array or something else then insert that data to your third database table

Comment: Basically i am making an application in which multiple messages will be stored on 0 to 9 keys by customization, a single message would be send to multiple contacts.

Comment: I made a database consists of three tables. First table named "message" having two fields "MESSAGE_ID" , "MESSAGE_TEXT"; second table named "contact" having two fields "CONTACT_ID" , "CONTACT_NUMBER"; third table named "KEY_TABLE" having two fields "MESSAGE_ID" & "CONTACT_ID , i want to fetch the MSG_ID from table MESSAGE and CONTACT_ID from the table CONTACT 
to link between & contacts.A specific contact can receive more than 1 message.