# SQLite equivalent of SELECT ... INTO in Access SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access query which takes some data from 2 separate tables (within the same database) and merges it into a newly created table, the SQL is as follows:

`SELECT Student_Answers.Student_Login, Student_Answers.Question_ID, Student_Answers.Status, Student_Answers.TimeStamp, Student_Answers.Student_Answer, Questions.Question_type, Questions.Question_ID INTO [tempAnswered&Unasweredwith_UI]`

`FROM (Questions LEFT JOIN Student_Answers ON Questions.Question_ID = Student_Answers.Question_ID)`

`WHERE (((Student_Answers.Student_Login)<>'10l.delbasso' Or (Student_Answers.Student_Login) Is Null));"`

When running the same Query in SQLite it tells me that the "**INTO**" command is not supported. I have tried finding solutions online (for example translators between Access and SQLite) but i cannot find a solution as my problem seems to be quite specific. If anyone could help me to get the SQLite query working i would appreciate it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027488/sqlite-select-into. Use the CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259565/2144390) to a similar question, SQLite supports

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1
```

which you can use in place of the `SELECT ... INTO table2 FROM table1` form that Access SQL uses.

Comment: How would i implement this in such a way that it selects data from 2 tables and inserts it into table 2?

Comment: Have the SELECT portion pull the information from the two source tables with an appropriate JOIN between them. In other words, formulate the SELECT part (without the INTO) to give the results you want, then stick `CREATE TABLE table2 AS ` onto the beginning.